# Set column width to zero in GWT GRID or FLEX TABLE

Tags: gwt, grid, width, flextable

I am trying to set the column width to zero in a GWT-GRID in order to make it hidden.
I tried

```
grid.GetColumnFormatter().setWidth(0, "0px");
```

But nothing happened.Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In grid, whether you use `FlexTableFormatter()` or `ColumnFormatter()`, each column will occupy its size. In case if you want to resctrict it by some pixels you can do it. But you can not make it 0. 
Rather you can make add particular column run time.